# parsing nested JSON array using volley library in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

How can I parse nested JSON array using volley library?
My JSON data structure screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/pbaea5

I need to perse score value.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("matches");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObjectMatchs = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        // bat_team node is JSON Object
        JSONObject bat_teamData = jsonObjectMatchs.getJSONObject("bat_team");
        JSONArray jsonArrayInnings = bat_teamData.getJSONArray("innings");
        JSONObject jsonObjectInnings = jsonArrayInnings.getJSONObject(i);


        String bat_team_score = jsonObjectInnings.getString("score");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate further on 
`jsonArrayInnings` using another loop but in your code you are using `i` of parent loop.
It will not work properly.